# Call Jython Method from wsadmin ant task

Tags: websphere, jython, websphere-8, wsadmin

I created a method in Jython to add shared library to the installed application. I save the script file in {was.install.dir}/bin directory with name "addSharedLib.py". I am using ant to install the application on the cluster. My question is how do I call this jython method from ant script to get desired result? I am using websphere 8.5.5 ND.

```
def setSharedLibrary(appName,editionNo,saredLibName):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have looked into the `WAS` provided ant environment?
There is `ws_ant` utility - [ws_ant docs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tovr_ant.html?lang=en).

Comment: This is the thing i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain one of the jython standalone jars from http://www.jython.org/downloads.html and just run the Ant java task like this ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<project default="install">
  <target name="install">
    <java classname="org.python.util.jython" fork="true" failonerror="true">
      <arg line="addSharedLib.py"/>
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location='D:\work\jython\jython2.5.3\jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar' />
      </classpath>
    </java>
  </target>
</project>
```